# Matplotlib.imshow, adjust scale and origin

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

I have an astronomical image that I have plotted with `matplotlib.imshow`.  Currently (as is the default), the ticks and tick labels correspond to the pixels of the image plotted with `imshow`.

I want to change both the tick positions and labels to be a different scale than "pixel" and to have an arbitrary origin.  I know the conversion from pixel size to the scale I'm using.  I'm unsure, though, how to create a new set of ticks with a different scale than the current pixel one used and with a different origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a conversion function like

```
f = lambda pixel: 2*pixel - 10
```

you can apply it to the extent of the image,

```
im = plt.imshow(data)
im.set_extent([f(x) for x in im.get_extent()])
```